# Please help me understand these sentences: それで？　いつになれば俺のお嫁さんになってくれる？

Tags: translation

I have just started learning Japanese, so if it's possible, please explain fully and clearly with the knowledge that I am a complete beginner in regards to Japanese grammar and vocabulary.

At this point, all I know is the hiragana, katakana, and various kanji (I know Mandarin). However, Japanese grammar is so different compared to English and Mandarin.

I would greatly appreciate an explanation of the Japanese text:

> それで？ いつになれば俺のお嫁さんになってくれる？

This was a dialogue in a game (I believe), however I don't know the overall context of this text.　The text was a bit blurry, so *I'm not sure* if it was ば　or ぱ* **it is** ば.

Please correct my attempt at translation. To my understanding, in English it is something like:

> And so?　When to become my bride...　do for me/let me have?

（And the "I" is a male?） I believe he is talking to a female.

Is it about a man asking a woman to be his bride? Or something similar? I'm very confused.

Comment: translation request will be hold :-P
 
それ that (what she told to him). で with. それで and then (I accept what you told). いつ when. に at. なれば if it would become(なる become. ば assumption). 俺 I(rude expression used by a male). の of(俺の my). お(polite effect to the following noun 嫁). 嫁 bride. さん(polite address). に to (indicate direction, place to be bound for). なって (なる become). くれる give it to me(what you intend to become for me).

Then, when do you become of my bride? (I'm not good at English -:)

Comment: あーん？いつ俺の嫁になる？ is a more rude, manly version.

Comment: Maybe you should try something more suitable for a beginner than this.

Answer (score 2):

[それで](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7) -- Then,/So,/And,...
いつになれば --> [いつになったら](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89) -- When, How long do I have to wait till...
俺のお嫁さん -- my bride 
に -- case particle 
なってくれる？ -- verb なる(become) + conjunctive particle て + subsidiary verb [くれる](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=66)(will you do me the favor of...?)

Comment: で？いつなってくれるの？(///▽///)